# SQL optimization on multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have one job scheduler which picked the updated  record from multiple table. it will pick the updated record from any of the table got updated below.
so I am using greatest function to filter that. I am storing highest value in column ecc_last_update_date .

My performance team has raised flag on it, suggesting find other way including temp table option.
Can you suggest some smart way for handling on it.

```
greatest(pp.last_update_date, pt.last_update_date, pei.last_update_date, pet.last_update_date, pe.last_update_date,
                     nvl(pap.last_update_date, pp.last_update_date), nvl(pj.last_update_date, pp.last_update_date), nvl(ap1.last_update_date,
                     pp.last_update_date))   as ecc_last_update_date
```

below query is picking updated record.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CST_ECC_VAL_WIP_ACC_SUMMARY 
WHERE ecc_last_update_date >= to_date(to_char(to_timestamp('08-DEC-20'), 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS'),'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS')
```

anyway I can improve greatest function so that it does not scan all the records? or any better way to do it?

```
select * from ( SELECT DISTINCT 'PROJ_SO' || '-' || ool.project_id || '-' || NVL( TO_CHAR(ool.task_id), 'NO_TASK' ) || '-' || ooh.header_id || '-' || ool.line_id AS ecc_spec_id, 'PROJ_SO' AS record_type, otype.language AS language, GREATEST( NVL( pp.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( pt.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ool.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ooh.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( otype.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( oterm.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( mif.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ship_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ship_loc.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ship_party_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ship_acct_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( bill_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( bill_loc.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( bill_party_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( bill_acct_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) ) AS ecc_last_update_date, pp.project_id AS project_id, pp.segment1 AS project_number, pp.org_id AS org_id, pt.task_id AS task_id, pt.task_number AS task_number, ool.line_id AS so_line_id, ooh.header_id AS so_header_id, TO_CHAR(ooh.order_number) AS so_number, oe_flex_util.get_concat_value(ool.line_number, ool.shipment_number, ool.option_number, ool.component_number, ool.service_number) AS so_line_number, ooh.cust_po_number AS cust_po_number, ooh.order_category_code AS so_category, otype.name AS so_type, mif.segment1 AS item_number, msitl.description AS item_description, ool.end_item_unit_number AS end_item_unit_number, lookup1.meaning AS so_freight_terms, oterm.name AS so_payment_terms, soldto.customer_id AS so_customer_id, soldto.customer_number AS so_customer_number, soldto.name AS so_customer_name, ooh.ordered_date AS so_order_date, ooh.request_date AS so_request_date, DECODE( ool.ordered_quantity, 0, 'Yes', 'No' ) AS so_cancelled_flag, DECODE( ship_loc.city, NULL , NULL , ship_loc.city || ', ' ) || DECODE( ship_loc.postal_code, NULL , NULL , ship_loc.postal_code || ', ' ) || DECODE( ship_loc.country, NULL , NULL , ship_loc.country ) AS ship_to_location, oe_org_addresses.ship_to_org_id AS ship_to_location_id, NVL( ool.shipping_method_code, ooh.shipping_method_code ) AS ship_method, lookup2.meaning AS ship_priority, DECODE( ooh.partial_shipments_allowed, 'Y', 'Yes', 'N', 'No' ) AS partial_ship, oe_org_addresses.bill_to_org_id AS bill_to_location_id, DECODE( bill_loc.city, NULL , NULL , bill_loc.city || ', ' ) || DECODE( bill_loc.postal_code, NULL , NULL , bill_loc.postal_code || ', ' ) || DECODE( bill_loc.country, NULL , NULL , bill_loc.country ) AS bill_to_location, DECODE( ool.line_category_code, 'RETURN', (-1) * ( NVL( ool.ordered_quantity, 0 ) - NVL( ool.cancelled_quantity, 0 ) ) , (NVL( ool.ordered_quantity, 0 ) - NVL( ool.cancelled_quantity, 0 ) )) * NVL( ool.unit_selling_price, 0 ) AS so_line_amount, ooh.transactional_curr_code AS currency_code, DECODE( NVL( ool.tax_exempt_flag, ooh.tax_exempt_flag ) , 'S', 'Standard', 's', 'Standard', 'E', 'Exempt', 'e', 'Exempt', 'R', 'Required', 'r', 'Required', NVL( ool.tax_exempt_flag, ooh.tax_exempt_flag ) ) AS so_tax_exempt, hou.name AS warehouse FROM pa_projects_all pp, pa_tasks pt, oe_order_lines_all ool, oe_order_headers_all ooh, oe_transaction_types_tl otype, ra_terms_tl oterm, mtl_system_items_b mif, mtl_system_items_tl msitl, oe_lookups lookup1, oe_lookups lookup2, hz_cust_site_uses_all ship_site, hz_locations ship_loc, hz_party_sites ship_party_site, hz_cust_acct_sites_all ship_acct_site, hz_cust_site_uses_all bill_site, hz_locations bill_loc, hz_party_sites bill_party_site, hz_cust_acct_sites_all bill_acct_site, hr_organization_units hou, ( SELECT ool.line_id, NVL( ool.ship_to_org_id, ooh.ship_to_org_id ) AS ship_to_org_id, NVL( ool.invoice_to_org_id, ooh.invoice_to_org_id ) AS bill_to_org_id FROM oe_order_lines_all ool, oe_order_headers_all ooh WHERE ooh.header_id = ool.header_id AND ool.project_id IS NOT NULL)oe_org_addresses, ( SELECT cust_acct.cust_account_id AS organization_id, party.party_name AS name, cust_acct.cust_account_id AS customer_id, cust_acct.account_number AS customer_number FROM hz_parties party, hz_cust_accounts cust_acct WHERE cust_acct.party_id = party.party_id)soldto WHERE pp.project_type != 'AWARD_PROJECT' AND pp.template_flag != 'Y' AND pp.project_id = ool.project_id AND pt.task_id(+) = ool.task_id AND ooh.header_id = ool.header_id AND oterm.term_id(+) = ooh.payment_term_id AND otype.transaction_type_id = ooh.order_type_id AND soldto.organization_id(+) = ooh.sold_to_org_id AND mif.inventory_item_id = ool.inventory_item_id AND mif.organization_id = ool.ship_from_org_id AND msitl.inventory_item_id = mif.inventory_item_id AND msitl.organization_id = mif.organization_id AND msitl.language = otype.language AND lookup1.lookup_code(+) = ooh.freight_terms_code AND lookup1.lookup_type(+) = 'FREIGHT_TERMS' AND lookup2.lookup_code(+) = ooh.shipment_priority_code AND lookup2.lookup_type(+) = 'SHIPMENT_PRIORITY' AND oe_org_addresses.line_id = ool.line_id AND ship_site.site_use_id(+) = oe_org_addresses.ship_to_org_id AND ship_site.cust_acct_site_id = ship_acct_site.cust_acct_site_id(+) AND ship_acct_site.party_site_id = ship_party_site.party_site_id(+) AND ship_party_site.location_id = ship_loc.location_id(+) AND NVL( ship_site.org_id, -99 ) = NVL( ship_acct_site.org_id, -99 ) AND bill_site.site_use_id(+) = oe_org_addresses.bill_to_org_id AND bill_site.cust_acct_site_id = bill_acct_site.cust_acct_site_id(+) AND bill_acct_site.party_site_id = bill_party_site.party_site_id(+) AND bill_party_site.location_id = bill_loc.location_id(+) AND NVL( bill_site.org_id, -99 ) = NVL( bill_acct_site.org_id, -99 ) AND hou.organization_id(+) = ool.ship_from_org_id AND otype.language = NVL( oterm.language, otype.language ) AND GREATEST( NVL( pp.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( pt.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ool.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ooh.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( otype.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( oterm.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( mif.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ship_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ship_loc.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ship_party_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( ship_acct_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( bill_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( bill_loc.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( bill_party_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) , NVL( bill_acct_site.last_update_date, to_date('01-01-1990', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) ) >= to_date('05-DEC-20','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') ;
```

Comment: Can you please post your entire query? I can see lots of aliases in the `GREATEST` function values. It would be helpful to answer you properly. One suggestion. You can directly use: `ECC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE >=  DATE '2020-12-08'`

Comment: I don't understand the overall task. I assume it's something like "tell me when was the latest update on the product" and so you scan the product table, the product prices table, the product delivery table, the product stock table, etc. to get that latest date. But then, how is "improve greatest function so that it does not scan all the records" supposed to work? How do you think could you get the *maximum* date without looking at *all* dates? How would you know the latest change the product had was in its stock record, without having checked when was the lastest price change for instance?

Comment: I have added the query. please see at the end in query

Comment: Wow, how old is this query? It's rare these days that we still see the 1980s join syntax. If I were you, changing this to explicit joins would be the first thing I'd do, just to get this readable. Then I'd check, why `DISTINCT` is necessary in that query. That is often an indicator for non-optimal access. And when showing us a query, you should at least format it instead of putting it in one line. The query only selects joined rows for which at least one date is current. Your best bet to get this quick may be to write triggers on all child tables and store the maximum date in the main entity.

Comment: Actually Thorsten I am new in Organization. This is oracle ebs legacy query

Comment: Based on this expression, it looks like somebody already spent the time to optimize the query to use full table scans and hash joins: `NVL( ship_site.org_id, -99 ) = NVL( ship_acct_site.org_id, -99 )`. This looks like a query that reads a large percentage of data, and index access could *decrease* performance. And temporary tables rarely improve performance in Oracle. You'll either need to provide a *lot* of extra data, like results from dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor, or find someone in your org with Oracle data warehouse tuning experience.

Comment: Thank you John. I am reading more about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your `GREATEST` condition with the `< ANY` condition. Also, You don't need `NVL` at all.

```
DATE '2020-12-05' < ANY (PP.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, PT.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 
                        OOL.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, OOH.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                        OTYPE.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, OTERM.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                        MIF.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SHIP_SITE.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                        SHIP_LOC.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SHIP_PARTY_SITE.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                        SHIP_ACCT_SITE.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, BILL_SITE.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                        BILL_LOC.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, BILL_PARTY_SITE.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                        BILL_ACCT_SITE.LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
```

**Tip of the day**: Always use `standard ANSI-joins`.